# Creating p:commandlink in Popups in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

How do I create `p:commandlink` in Popups can be called to a bean method like `actionListener="#{offLineMapsTestBean.fetchInstList(variable)}"`?

I tried with this code:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
        return feature;
    });
    if (feature) {
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        popup.setPosition(coordinates);
        $(element).popover({
                'placement' : 'top',
                'html' : true,
                'content' : 'Name:'+ feature.get('name')+ '\n'                                            + "<div id='test'> <button onclick= '#offLineMapsTestBean.fetchInstList(feature.get('name'))}'>  </button></div>" 
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
    } else {
        $(element).popover('destroy');
    }
});
```

Comment: '<a   href="../menu/somepage.html">'+feature.get('name')+'</a> '

Comment: Please do not add comments; instead, **edit** your post to include the information

Answer (score -1):

''+feature.get('name')+' ' this can work for redirecting page

Comment: Are you saying that you have fixed your own problem with this line?